# Value transfer from inner to outer class

Tags: python, oop

I have an outer `Class A` and an inner `Class B`. I thought this would work like this: I create an object of `Class A` first `obj=A(4)`. If I now create an object of `Class B` with `obj.B(5)` this object is bound to `Object A` and the value (in this case 5) is saved within Objects A instance. If this would be the case I could call `obj.A.foo_a()` and this should print `5`. It looks like the information 5 is lost on the way or gets never saved in A. So it does not. Could anyone tell me where I am getting wrong?

```
class A:
    def __init__(self, value_a):
        self.value_a = value_a
        self.b = self.B()
    def foo_a(self):
        foo_b()

    class B:
        def __init__(self, value_b=None):
            self.value_b = value_b
        def foo_b(self):
            print(value_b)

obj = A(4)
obj.B(5)
obj.foo_a()
```

Comment: "this object is bound to Object A and the value (in this case 5) is saved within Objects A instance" No, that isn't what happens at all. The class object `B` belongs to the namespace of the class object `A`, but there is no inherent connection between their instances. `foo_b` is not accessible in `foo_a`'s scope, btw, it would require `A.B.foo_b`

Comment: Your code doesn't even run. You're missing a parameter in the `B` constructor in this line: `self.b = self.B()`. And `foo_b()` is out of scope when you call it within `foo_a`. Please post the actual code that is giving you the problems you've described.

Comment: `self.b = self.B(<require some value here>)`

Comment: You seem to have a fundamental misunderstand of the semantics of nesting a class. In general, nested classes are not a common pattern in Python. All it does is affect namespaces, but it doesn't create any sort of data-sharing between instances of these classes. IOW, `obj.B(5)` creates a `B` object, which doesn't get assigned to anything, and thus, gets immediately discarded/garbage collected. It no longer even exists by the time you get to `obj.foo_a()`

Comment: `print(value_b)` should probably be `print(self.value_b)`.